# How to modify and resend packet in network

Tags: arp, libnet

I'm doing an exercise ARP sniffing.

I want to simulate a attack like Man in The Middle. 
I had been sending arp to change way packet to Attacker PC.
But I don't know How to forwarding this packet I receive from A to B.

How I do it? Can I do it with LibIPQ, or Libnet.

Answer (score 0):

Recomend to read this post:

Spoofing the ARP Table of Remote Computers on a LAN 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/winarpspoof.aspx
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/network/basicnetworkoperations/article.php/c6861

and need view this proyect SharpPcap.

and not forget read: [Can you use ARP-Poisoning (spoofing) to apply simulated external effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794687/can-you-use-arp-poisoning-spoofing-to-apply-simulated-external-effects)

Salute.

Comment: On this page you can find an example: http://hi.baidu.com/_wang8/blog/item/5b7bda2bfd10b0eae6cd40ef.html